# Recursively scraping using multiple logins?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to scrape a webpage using multiple logins (i.e. I need to check details for multiple users). I'm using the CrawlSpider from scrapy.contrib.spiders. I can the CrawlSpider working for simple parsing, e.g.

```
def parse(self,response):
    for site in sites:
        yield Response(...)
```

But in my case, I need to log in first, then go another page and parse that one. So I have something like this:

```
def parse(self,response):
    for user in users:
        yield FormRequest.fromResponse(response,formData={login details},callback=self.after_login)

def after_login(self,response):
    return FormRequest.fromResponse(<some other URL requiring login>,callback=self.after_query)

def after_query(self,response):
    Parse the response and store to Items
    return None
```

In this case, it works for the first user, but then stops without any obvious error message. How can I get the recursion working so that all users info gets scraped?

Edit: As requested, here is the output I get running crawl

```
2014-02-27 15:25:36-0600 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.22.0 started (bot: bot)
2014-02-27 15:25:36-0600 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11, django
2014-02-27 15:25:36-0600 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE':'bot.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['bot.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'bot'}
2014-02-27 15:25:36-0600 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: LogStats, TelnetConsole,CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, SpiderState
2014-02-27 15:25:37-0600 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2014-02-27 15:25:37-0600 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2014-02-27 15:25:37-0600 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: 
2014-02-27 15:25:37-0600 [site_parse] INFO: Spider opened
2014-02-27 15:25:37-0600 [site_parse] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2014-02-27 15:25:37-0600 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 0.0.0.0:6023
2014-02-27 15:25:37-0600 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 0.0.0.0:6080
2014-02-27 15:25:38-0600 [site_parse] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.thesite.com> (referer: None)
2014-02-27 15:25:39-0600 [site_parse] DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <POST http://www.thesite.com/security/loginhandler.php> - no more duplicates will be shown (see DUPEFILTER_CLASS)
2014-02-27 15:25:40-0600 [site_parse] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://www.thesite.com/main.php?state=0> from <POST http://www.thesite.com/security/loginhandler.php>
2014-02-27 15:25:48-0600 [site_parse] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.thesite.com/main.php?state=0> (referer: http://www.thesite.com)
2014-02-27 15:25:56-0600 [site_parse] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.thesite.com/action.php?action_type=2&object_id=7748> (referer: http://www.thesite.com/main.php?state=0)
2014-02-27 15:25:56-0600 [site_parse] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2014-02-27 15:25:56-0600 [site_parse] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 1421,
 'downloader/request_count': 4,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 3,
 'downloader/request_method_count/POST': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 2653755,
 'downloader/response_count': 4,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 3,
 'downloader/response_status_count/302': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 27, 21, 25, 56, 515692),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 7,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'request_depth_max': 2,
 'response_received_count': 3,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 4,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 4,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 4,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 4,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 27, 21, 25, 37, 233155)}
2014-02-27 15:25:56-0600 [game_parse] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: Please post the traceback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the logs your second request is filtered as being duplicate.

```
2014-02-27 15:25:39-0600 [site_parse] DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <POST http://www.thesite.com/security/loginhandler.php> - no more duplicates will be shown (see DUPEFILTER_CLASS)
```

You can solve this issue by setting **dont_filter** argument for the Request.

```
FormRequest.fromResponse(<some other URL requiring login>,callback=self.after_query, dont_filter=True)
```

Comment: That did the trick. I actually needed to add it to the first request as well. Thankyou.